# This expression is true in Python: {}.keys().insert(0, "") == None. Why?

Tags: python

Look to my Python session:

```
>>> {}.keys().insert(0, "") == None
True
```

but:

```
>>> k = {}.keys()
>>> k
[]
>>> k.insert(0, "")
>>> k
['']
```

Why??

**PS**. Thanks for help! Python have very strange design - do not support chaining:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

That is root of my problem...

Comment: Python supports method chaining *on immutable objects.* On mutable objects, like lists, this would create confusion as to whether a new object was being returned or the existing one being mutated. The fact that such methods on mutable objects returns `None` lets you know right away that the existing object is being mutated, and if your assumption is otherwise, you find out very quickly when you run the code, rather than when you need to track down tricky bugs resulting from your false assumption.

Comment: @kindall. thanks for explanation because I start think why Python doesn't provide chaining... +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`list.insert` *returns* `None`; when you print `k` you're printing the new state of the list.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the return type to `None` in case 1 which would evaluate to `True`.
Python `insert` returns `None`